# Why do I get a recursion call runtime error?

Tags: c++, stack-overflow

I expected the code below to print the sequence **0 1 2 3**.

Instead I got a recursion call runtime error (causing a stack overflow).

Can you explain why ?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

#define ll long long
void print(int n)
{
    if (n < 0)
        return;
    if (n == 0)
    {
        cout << n << " ";
        return;
    }
    print(n--);
    cout << n << " ";
}
int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    int num = 3;
    print(num);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the actual  error?

Comment: Every time a compiler encounters `#define ll long long`, a fairy dies. In fact the first three non-blank lines reduce a grown man to tears.

Comment: And every time I see `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` I kill a fairy myself. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: Please do not learn how to code from "competition websites". They teach absolute _trash_ programming.

Comment: With `print(n--);` you are always calling the `print` function with the ***same value***. After the call returns, the local `n` will be 1 less, but that value is lost. Look up the difference between post-increment and pre-increment operators.

Comment: What do you think the value of `n--` is?

Comment: and every time I see [`using namespace std;` many fairies die](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/995714)

Comment: the problem would be known right away with a debugger. You must learn how to debug. See [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/995714), [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You should learn to use a debugger. Setting a breakpoint at the beginning of `print` would show you that `n` never changes and that your recursion would never and leading to exceeding of the stack.

Comment: *according to me it should run fine and my output is 0 1 2 3* -- That's not how computer programming works.  The computer does exactly what you tell it -- it has no idea what your desired output is -- all it does is follow the instructions given.   If the instructions given are faulty, then it's time for you to learn how to debug your code to see where *your* fault is.

Comment: I recommend you get out of the habit of using [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/10077) and [`#include <bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/10077). They're bad individually, but especially insidious together.

Comment: Don't write `n--` or `--n` when you mean `n-1`. Don't write `n++` or `++n` when you mean `n+1`. (Mutation is  bad, mmkay?) You don't even save a keystroke by doing it.

Comment: `#define ll long long` -- There is no need for stuff like this, when C++ already has `int64_t`.  The `int64_t`, not only describes that it is an integer, it also tells you the number of bits (64).  Using crazy macros like `ll` that look like the number `11` is unnecessary.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: `std::int64_t` even tells you something about the complementing scheme, although so does `long long` too from C++20. Although note well the common misconception that large values wrap around - the behavior of signed integral type overflow is still undefined.

Comment: @AdrianMole: if you have found a duplicate, by all means VTC.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this:

```
print(n--);
```

Here, the recursive call is made with the same value of `n` as it was called with. The decrement isn't performed until *after* the recursive call returns. The recursion is therefore theoretically infinite.

Rather, I don't believe you need to increment or decrement `n` at all. Just use `n-1`:

```
print(n-1);
```

Comment: pre*decrement*.

Comment: or avoid increment/decrement operators completely and only use them alone in a single line